# jQuery - Lightgallery.js - Detect approaching end of slidehsow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know what kind of condition I can use in the code below to establish whether the slideshow is nearing its end?

In other words, if there are fewer than 4 images left in the slideshow, send a new ajax call and append the response to the current response.

I manage to get the index of each image, but the condition I'm using below, i.e. `if (index > 2)` obviously fails because it triggers the ajax call on any subsequent item, and the number of items in each slideshow will vary, so a fixed number won't do. Below is what I have so far.

Also in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/grjp0928/5/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#links").lightGallery({
        selector: '.img-wrap',
        html:true,
        speed: 300,
    });     
    var $lg = $('#links');     
    $lg.lightGallery(); 
    $lg.on('onBeforeSlide.lg',function(event, index, fromTouch, fromThumb){        
        console.log(index, fromTouch, fromThumb);        
        if (index > 2) { // This doesn't work
            // Trigger new ajax call
            // Append items in response to current slidewhow
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the fiddle doesnt seem to be firing your custom events for some reason - not quite sure what is up with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you subtract your buffer number (two in this case) from the length of the elements with `.img-wrap`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#links").lightGallery({
        selector: '.img-wrap',
        html:true,
        speed: 300,
    });     

    var $lg = $('#links');
    var bufferThreshold = 2;//number of images remaining before we fetch more

    $lg.lightGallery();

    $lg.on('onBeforeSlide.lg',function(event, index, fromTouch, fromThumb){
        console.log(index, fromTouch, fromThumb);
        if (index > $('.img-wrap').length - bufferThreshold) {
            //almost done, get more!
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You nailed it, matey! Thanks a lot. Any idea how to prevent it from firing on all the remaining items after the buffer? In other words, only allow it to be triggered once, namely when the threshold is met?

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. If the new elements you add have a class of `.img-wrap`, the length of `$('.img-wrap').length ` should be longer. In this case you wouldnt come into the `if` block until you come to the end of the new images - so you could potentially keep on requesting images forever...